# Is Gzip compressed binary data or uncompressed text safe to transmit over https, or should it be base 64 encoded as the final step before sending it?

Tags: https, base64, gzip, content-encoding

My question is in the title, this provides context to help you understand my confusion. Everything is sent over https.

My understanding of base 64 encoding is that it is a way of representing binary data as text, such that the text is safe to transmit across networks or the internet because it avoids anything that might be interpreted as a control code by the various possible protocols that might be involved at some point.

Given this understanding, I am confused why everything sent to over the internet is not base 64 encoded. When is it safe not to base 64 encode something before sending it? I understand that not everything understands or expects to receive things in base 64, but my question is why doesn't everything expect and work with this if it is the only way to send data without the possibility it could be interpreted as control codes?

I am designing an Android app and server API such that the app can use the API to send data to the server. There are some potentially large SQLite database files the client will be sending to the server (I know this sounds strange, yes it needs to send the entire database files). They are being gzipped prior to uploading. I know there is also a header that can be used to indicate this: `Content-Encoding: gzip`. Would it be safe to compress the data and send it with this header without base 64 encoding it? If not, why does such a header exist if it is not safe to use? I mean, if you base 64 encode it first and then compress it, you undo the point of base 64 encoding and it is not at that point base 64 encoded. If you compress it first and then base 64 encode it, that header would no longer be valid as it is not in the compressed format at that point. We actually don't want to use the header because we want to save the files in a compressed state, and using the header will cause the server to decompress it prior to our API code running. I'm only asking this to further clarify why I am confused about whether it is safe to send gzip compressed data without base 64 encoding it.

My best guess is that it depends on if what you are sending is binary data or not. If you are sending binary data, it should be base 64 encoded as the final step before uploading it. But if you are sending text data, you may not need to do this. However it still seems to my logic, this might still depends on the character encoding used. Perhaps some character encodings can result in sending data that could be interpreted as a control code? If this is true, which character encodings are safe to send without base 64 encoding them as the final step prior to sending it? If I am correct about this, it implies you should only use the that gzip header if you are sending compressed text that has not been base 64 encoded. Does compressing it create the possibility of something that could be interpreted as a control code?

I realize this was rather long, so I will repeat my primary questions (the title) here: Is either Gzip compressed binary data or uncompressed text safe to transmit, or should it be base 64 encoded as the final step before sending it? Okay I lied there is one more question involved in this. Would sending gzip compressed text always be safe to send without base 64 encoding it at the end, no matter which character encoding it had prior to compression?

Comment: Transferring data across systems is safe so long as it conforms to the specification of the protocols being used (I'm assuming you're referring to HTTP).  See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-7.2 on entity body for restrictions.  To answer your specific question, you can send binary data as an entity-body without base64 encoding it (compressed or otherwise).

Comment: @Matthew Thank you. Yes, it is using https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding of base 64 encoding is that it is a way of representing binary data as text,

Specifically, as text consisting of characters drawn from a 64-character set, plus a couple of additional characters serving special purposes.

> such that the text is safe to transmit across networks or the internet because it avoids anything that might be interpreted as a control code by the various possible protocols that might be involved at some point.

That's a bit of an overstatement.  For two endpoints to communicate with each other, they need to agree on **one** protocol.  If another protocol becomes involved along the way, then it is the responsibility of the endpoints for *that* transmission to handle any needed encoding considerations for it.

What bytes and byte combinations can successfully be conveyed is a matter of the protocol in use, and there are plenty that handle binary data just fine.

At one time there was also an issue that some networks were not 8-bit clean, so that bytes with numeric values greater than 127 could not be conveyed across those networks, but that is not a practical concern today.

> Given this understanding, I am confused why everything sent to over the internet is not base 64 encoded.

Given that the understanding you expressed is seriously flawed, it is not surprising that you are confused.

> When is it safe not to base 64 encode something before sending it?

It is not only safe but essential to avoid base 64 encoding when the recipient of the transmission expects something different.  The two or more parties to a given transmission must agree about the protocol to be used.  That establishes the acceptable parameters of the communication.  Although Base 64 is an available option for part or all of a message, it is by no means the only one, nor is it necessarily the best one for binary data, much less for data that are textual to begin with.

> I understand that not everything understands or expects to receive things in base 64, but my question is why doesn't everything expect and work with this if it is the only way to send data without the possibility it could be interpreted as control codes?

Because it is not by any means the only way to avoid data being misinterpreted.

> They are being gzipped prior to uploading. I know there is also a header that can be used to indicate this: `Content-Encoding: gzip`. Would it be safe to compress the data and send it with this header without base 64 encoding it?

It would be *expected* to transfer such data without base-64 encoding it.  HTTP(S) handles binary data just fine. The `Content-Encoding` header tells the recipient how to interpret the message body, and if it specifies a binary content type (such as gzip) then binary data conforming to that content type are what the recipient will expect.

> My best guess is that it depends on if what you are sending is binary data or not.

No.  These days, for all practical intents and purposes, it depends only on what application-layer protocol you are using for the transmission.  If it specifies that some or all of the message is to be base-64 encoded (according to a particular base-64 scheme, as there are more than one) then that's what the sender must do and how the receiver will interpret the message.  If the protocol does not specify that, then the sender must not perform base-64 encoding.  Some protocols afford the sender the option to make this choice, but those also provide a way for the sender to indicate inside the transmission what choice has been made.

> Is either Gzip compressed binary data or uncompressed text safe to transmit, or should it be base 64 encoded as the final step before sending it?

Neither is inherently unsafe to transmit on today's networks.  Whether data are base-64 encoded for transmission is a question of agreement between sender and receiver.

> Okay I lied there is one more question involved in this. Would sending gzip compressed text always be safe to send without base 64 encoding it at the end, no matter which character encoding it had prior to compression?

The character encoding of the uncompressed text is not a factor in whether a gzipped version can be safely and successfully conveyed.  But it probably matters for the receiver or anyone to whom they forward that data to understand the uncompressed text correctly.  If you intend to accommodate multiple character encodings then you will want to provide a way to indicate which applies to each text.

Comment: Thank you. A previous commenter helped me realize my question needs to be protocol specific. Our app and server communicate with each other over https.

Comment: And I do speak to HTTP(S) in this answer, @still_dreaming_1, but it sounds like you may still have the wrong idea.  I wouldn't say that the question is protocol specific, but rather that whether and how data should be encoded for transmission is a function of the protocol in use.  HTTP(S) supports any content type you can imagine, text or binary, and base-64 is an aspect of that content type, not an additional consideration on top of it.

Comment: Would you say that over https, there is no reason to design a server API or app to require/use base 64 encoding when sending data to each other? If this is true, it seems like a missing piece of the conversation when people explain the purpose of base 64 encoding. It seems they should point out it would be an unnecessary design choice over https.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1, I would say that it is generally unnecessary and unhelpful for a server API or app to require or use base-64 encoding for communicating over the network, especially via HTTP(S).  There may be special case exceptions.  If there is something missing in explanations of Base 64 it is probably that it was devised as a solution to a collection of related problems that are much less often relevant today than they once were.